# Move canvas element into desired position

Tags: javascript, html, css, canvas

I've tried to look for the answer to this everywhere but I don't seem to find it. But I want to move the text created from an input to a specific position in the canvas, say, on the top centre.

The code runs like this: ([JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/rmusngi/zzugthuk/2/))

```
    <canvas id="canvas" style="background-color: #000" width="800px" height="300px"></canvas>

<input type="text" id="header-text" placeholder="Your Title">
```

Meanwhile, the js looks like:

```
var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas'),
    ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');


  document.getElementById('header-text').addEventListener('keyup', function() {
    var stringTitle = document.getElementById('header-text').value;
    console.log(stringTitle)

    ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
    ctx.fillStyle = '#fff';
    ctx.font = 'bold 36px Arial';
    ctx.textAlign = 'center'; 
    var text_title = stringTitle;
    ctx.fillText(stringTitle, 15, canvas.height / 2 + 35);
    });
```

Is there a way where I can move the text generated to the top centre? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, you can use math to calculate the right position. 
You used:

```
ctx.fillText(stringTitle, 15, canvas.height / 2 + 35);
```

so to change the text position to top center you can use something like this:

```
ctx.fillText(stringTitle, canvas.width/2, canvas.height / 8 + 35);
```

Comment: Ouch! Using hard-coded y-offsets (or even y-offsets based on font size) is not very precise. Instead, use `context.setBaseline` which is made for the exact purpose of vertically aligning text.

Comment: You are right. Your answer is better, my bad. I'm still learning JS ;)

Answer (score 0):

To have text in top center:

`ctx.fillText(stringTitle, canvas.width / 2, 36);`

Where `36` is size of your font (height).
If you need more precision while positioning text horizontally, you could use
*[CanvasRenderingContext2D.measureText()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/measureText)*.